# Application.Current.MainWindow is null in startup event handler

Tags: wpf

I have a strong background in windows forms, and I'm starting to work in WPF.  Consider the following event handler in my Application code behind:

```
Private Sub Application_Startup(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.StartupEventArgs) Handles Me.Startup
    Debug.Print(Application.Current.MainWindow Is Nothing)
End Sub
```

This prints "True", meaning the `Application.Current.MainWindow` is null.  How can I access the main window instance as soon as the application is run?  (i.e. I know this event is fired [as soon as the application is run](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.application.startup%28v=vs.110%29.aspx))

Answer (score 8, accepted):

"If you need access to the main window during startup, you need to manually create a new window object from your Startup event handler." - source: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.application.startup(v=vs.110).aspx

So basically you will have to create your main window when the Application.Startup event is called. Also you can remove `StartupUri="MainWindow"` from your App.xaml and simply show the instance of main window you create.

App.xaml

```
<Application x:Class="Namespace.App"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml" <---- Remove this
             Startup="Application_Startup"
             >
    <Application.Resources>

    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

App.xaml.cs

```
private void Application_Startup(object sender, StartupEventArgs e)
{
    MainWindow wnd = new MainWindow();
    wnd.Show();
}
```

I hope this answers your question.

Comment: Thanks a lot.  I hadn't see that note about creating your own window.